# Find an explicit Noether normalization

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $k$ be an infinite field and let $f \in k[x_1,...,x_n]\setminus\{0\}$.  Define $A = k[x_1,...,x_n, f^{-1}]$ as subring of $k(x_1,...,x_n)$. Find a Noether normalization of $A$.

I am not sure if my approach is correct, but I think I first need to check if $x_1,...,x_n, f^{-1}$ are algebraically dependent, which they are, because if I define $g \in k[y_1,...,y_{n+1}]$ as $g=f(y_1,...,y_n)y_{n+1}-1$ then $g(x_1,...,x_n, f^{-1})=0$.

Is this correct? And what do I do now?

Comment: That is certainly a good place to start.  Now recall $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a UFD and write $f$ as ....

Comment: @user10354138 ... product of irreducible polynomials and a nonzero constant. Not sure how this helps me

Comment: I am not sure how explicit you want your normalization to be, but usually one would need to find a suitable change of variables at this stage, in order for your polynomial $g$ to be unitary in one of the new variables. One follows directly the proof of normalization as it gives the recipe.